# SQL server 2008 R2 Scalar function does not work

Tags: sql-server, function

I have this function, which should bring me the end of month date of an invoice.

E.g. Invoice (ARID) have a created date 2015-09-1, the eom is 2015-09-30.

```
ALTER  FUNCTION [dbo].[sfEOM](@ARID int, @Switch int) 
RETURNS date 
AS
BEGIN    

declare @Letzter date
declare @MaxLeistungsdatum as date


if @Switch=1     
set @Letzter = (select CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF   (MONTH,0,tblleistungen.LeistungsDatum),30),0) from dbo.tblleistungen where ARID=@ARID group by ARID,CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,tblleistungen.LeistungsDatum),30),0) )

else
set @MaxLeistungsdatum=(select max(LeistungsDatum) from tblDatensaetzeBA where ARID=@ARID group by ARID)
set @Letzter = (select CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@MaxLeistungsdatum),30),0)) 

RETURN @Letzter
END
go
```

To use one function for two different tables I use as @Switch

but

```
select dbo.sfEOM(9307396,1)
```

or

```
select dbo.sfEOM(9307396,2)
```

brings NULL as result where as

```
select CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF   (MONTH,0,tblleistungen.LeistungsDatum),30),0) from dbo.tblleistungen where ARID9307396 group by ARID,CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,tblleistungen.LeistungsDatum),30),0)
```

brings the correct date.

When I omit if @Switch=1 and have only

```
set @Letzter = (select CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF   (MONTH,0,tblleistungen.LeistungsDatum),30),0) from dbo.tblleistungen where ARID=@ARID group by ARID,CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,tblleistungen.LeistungsDatum),30),0) )
```

it works too.

Whats wrong there?
Thanks!
Michael

Comment: Most likely you miss `begin ... end` in `else` section.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the code blocks for the `if` statement:

```
ALTER  FUNCTION [dbo].[sfEOM](@ARID int, @Switch int) 
RETURNS date 
AS
BEGIN    
    declare @Letzter date
    declare @MaxLeistungsdatum as date

    if @Switch = 1  
    begin   
        set @Letzter = (select CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF   (MONTH,0,tblleistungen.LeistungsDatum),30),0) from dbo.tblleistungen where ARID=@ARID group by ARID,CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,tblleistungen.LeistungsDatum),30),0) )
    end
    else
    begin
        set @MaxLeistungsdatum=(select max(LeistungsDatum) from tblDatensaetzeBA where ARID=@ARID group by ARID)
        set @Letzter = (select CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@MaxLeistungsdatum),30),0)) 
    end
    return @Letzter
end;
```

go

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!

But I had code blocks like These...
if @Switch=1 begin...end  if @Switch=2 begin..end   but it did not work!

Comment: @user3480989 . . . I cannot respond to what you had.  The query in your question does not have code blocks.